# Child function not getting invoked on Parent click- React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code snippet in React JS. its basically a accordion which a delete icon on it. on clicking on the parent i am calling `toggleAccordion` to open the accordion. also i have a `openDeleteConfirmation` to delete the item. But since i have a function `toggleAccordion` on the parent the child function `openDeleteConfirmation` is not getting invoked. any inputs to solve this issue will be highly appreciated .

```
        <Accordion
          variant="text"
          onClick={toggleAccordion})
          }
        >
          <div className={classes.carePlanHeaderCol}>
            Title
          </div>
          <div className={`${classes.carePlanHeaderCol} ${classes.carePlanFrequency}`}>
           frequency
          </div>
          <div className={classes.carePlanHeaderCol}>
           time
          </div>
          <div className={classes.carePlanEntryAction}>
            <span
              data-testid="delete-care-plan"
              className={classes.actionBtn}
              onClick={() => openDeleteConfirmation()}
            >
              <span className="fa fa-trash" />
            </span>
          </div>
        </Accordion>


 const Accordion = withStyles(({ mixins }: Theme) => ({
      root: {
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        display: "flex",
    
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: "transparent !important",
        },
      },
    
      label: {
        fontSize: 14,
        lineHeight: 1,
        textTransform: "none",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "flex-start",
        textAlign: "left"
      },
    
      endIcon: {
        fontSize: 12,
        marginBottom: 2,
        marginLeft: 4,
      },
    }))(Button);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Without seeing your structure and your hierarchy, this is just an educated guess .. But ..    Possibly the need to pass the function into your element, if it lives in a parent?  IE `<Accordian openDeleteConfirmation={openDeleteConfirmation} varient="text"  >`